# What is the difference between 'stand' and 'take a stand'?

Tags: grammar

> 1.You had to take a stand.
>
> 2.You had to stand.

What is the difference between 'stand' and 'take a stand' in meaning?

Comment: I think that you can easily find this out by looking in a dictionary. stand in the first sentence is a noun, and in the second sentence it is a verb.

Answer (score 8):

1. 'Taking a stand' means making a statement or having an opinion about something.
2. 'To stand' means to stand up; ordinarily to get up from a sitting position.

Comment: "Taking a stand" is much more than just *having* an opinion, it implies a certain resoluteness or confidence that means you are prepared to defend that position against critique or attack. As Zessa's answer suggests, it brings to mind an image of soldiers preparing to (literally, militarily) defend a location.

Comment: It's also worth noting the phrase "Take the stand", which is completely different from the other two definitions.

Answer (score 4):

1. Is an idiom, related to military terminology of 'making a stand'. To take a position and defend it. [Dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-a-stand/)
2. To stand, is the actual act of standing up.